# How to deploy a JavaFX project with maven, including custom and non-modular dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am currently in the process of trying to deploy my JavaFX application (either with a jar or an installer, however an installer would be preferred). I have seen some sources point to using jlink, in which I have tried to no avail.

While I would have no problem building normally with jlink, I am trying to include a custom serialization utility I made with Maven and Java 17 (no JavaFX, but it is a single modular with a module-info). To import this into my project, I am simply adding it as a dependency. Additionally, this dependency requires SnakeYAML, which I don't believe is a modular project? (Important later)

Now, with this dependency, if I try to run javafx:jlink, I typically get an error like "jlink does not work with automatic modules" (in reference to my serialization utility).

My setup:

- JavaFX 17.0.1
- JDK 17.0.1
- Maven 3.8.4
- IntelliJ IDEA ultimate

So, my main two questions:

- Should I even bother with jlink, especially if I am trying to get an installer?
- With modular projects like my JavaFX project, how do I add dependencies from other modular projects (and also, within the serialization utlity, somehow shade SnakeYAML) and allow them to be compiled with JavaFX?

Comment: I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70400382/revisions) your title.  Don’t ask for the best way to do things, it is subjective and will get your question closed.  Instead, just ask how to do things and see what answers you get, then vote for or accept the ones you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I even bother with jlink, especially if I am trying to get an installer?

No.

You can make use of jlink during the process, but, in my experience, it is not necessary. Also, the images jlink creates can be a little difficult to integrate with what is required by jpackage, which you will need to use anyway.

Instead, use `jpackage`, not `jlink` if you want an installer.

jpackage can both link your application and create an installer, but jlink can only link and cannot create an installer.

> With modular projects like my JavaFX project, how do I add dependencies from other modular projects (and also, within the serialization utlity, somehow shade SnakeYAML) and allow them to be compiled with JavaFX?

Don’t shade jars when packaging, it is not necessary.  Also, if the jars are modular, it will break their modularity and they might not work (for example the JavaFX jars are not supported when shaded into a jar).

To add compile dependencies, you are already using Maven, just use its compile dependency mechanism.

For jar dependencies which you have created yourself, use the Maven install command to install the dependencies into your local repository, or use the install facilities in your repository manager (e.g. jfrog artifactory), if you use one.

The modern maven build process and the IDE integrations (at least Idea anyway) will automatically configure the correct paths for compilation of the declared dependencies so that they are available from the module path if they are modular and the class path or as an automatic module if they are not modular.

Include the dependent jars in your package.  This can be done two ways:

- if the jars are modular, link the jars into the runtime image included in the package:

  - Both jlink and jpackage can do this, but when creating an installer, use jpackage for the linking not jlink as jpackage will ensure all files in the image are in the right location for the installer, but jlink will not, in my experience using Java 17 tools.
- if the jars are not modular, then include them in a lib directory in the package. In the startup script for your application, which is included in the package, place the lib directory for the non-modular library files on the class path, so that they can be found.

> Additionally, this dependency requires SnakeYAML, which I don't believe is a modular project?

Follow the tutorial at:

- https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

  - A description of JPackageScriptFX:

    > demonstrates how projects can use scripts to build self-contained, platform-specific executables and installers of their JavaFX applications via the jdeps, jlink, and jpackage tools
    >
    > the scripts do not try to create a fully modularized solution but instead try to enable existing projects / applications, which often use non-modularized 3rd party dependencies, to be packaged